# Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION or PROCEDURE does not exist

Tags: mysql

So I'm creating a function in MySQL and then trying to grant permission to use that function to a user and am unable to do so. Here's what I'm doing:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE rxhelp36_scbn$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `businessDayDiff` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `businessDayDiff` (start DATETIME, stop DATETIME) RETURNS TINYINT
  NO SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN 5 * (DATEDIFF(stop, start) DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440', 7 * WEEKDAY(start) + WEEKDAY(stop) + 1, 1);
END $$

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE rxhelp36_scbn.businessDayDiff TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION or PROCEDURE businessDayDiff does not exist
```

I don't get it. I /just/ defined the function - how does it not exist?

Comment: Is rxhelp36_scbn your current schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I needed to do `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION` instead of `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE`.

You'd think that if `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE` only worked on PROCEDUREs that the error message ought to say "Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE businessDayDiff does not exist" instead of "FUNCTION or PROCEDURE"...