# mysql error syntax in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql5

```
sql = """
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS schema_change;

delimiter ';;'
CREATE PROCEDURE schema_change() BEGIN

    if exists (select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 
    schema() and table_name = 'selectedairport' and column_name = 'GDP') 
    then
        alter table selectedairport drop column GDP;

    alter table selectedairport add column GDP DOUBLE;

end;;

delimiter ';'


CALL schema_change () ; DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS schema_change ;
"""
cursor6.execute(sql)
```

However, this produces the error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter ';;'\nCREATE PROCEDURE schema_change() BEGIN\n\n    if exists (select * f' at line 1")

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execute()` method (usually) only executes a single command at a time, so the script cannot be parsed, and anyway there is no support for `DELIMITER`; see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/98#issuecomment-25203971). Therefore, one solution is to have multiple calls:

```
cursor6.execute("""
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS schema_change
""")

cursor6.execute("""
CREATE PROCEDURE schema_change() BEGIN

    if exists (select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 
    schema() and table_name = 'selectedairport' and column_name = 'GDP') 
    then
        alter table selectedairport drop column GDP;
```

**NOTE**: There is a syntax error here, we need to further add:

```
    END IF;
```

Now continue as before:

```
    alter table selectedairport add column GDP DOUBLE;

end
""")

cursor6.execute("""
CALL schema_change () 
""")

# Or cursor6.callproc('schema_change')

cursor6.execute("""
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS schema_change
""")
```

Comment: It errors:pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10")

Comment: BTW, note that you can also do `cursor6.callproc('schema_change')` to call a stored procedure, probably slightly more efficiently than via SQL.

Comment: Aha! I noticed that there was a syntax error in the stored procedure - you need an `END IF` to match the `IF`.

Comment: Thanks,it works.But it Warning: (1305, 'PROCEDURE alldata.schema_change does not exist')
  result = self._query(query)

Comment: A quick search shows [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38559083/1270789) which suggests you need `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE alldata.schema_change TO 'myuser'@'localhost';` (or `ON FUNCTION `).